# Hiding secure django settings info on webfaction

Tags: django, webfaction

I am trying to hide secure info like database password of a django application on webfaction.
But I could not find how and where to set these infos using environmental variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to your `bash_profile`.

Once you SSH in run:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add your desired variables and save it. Example:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@host:port/databasename
```

This will create an environment variable named `DATABASE_URL` with the contents of your string. To test, run `echo $DATABASE_URL` in your terminal.

Comment: Can all python versions  accsess those vars?

Comment: Yes. The easiest way to parse the database string above is to use the `dj-database-url` package found [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url). In general though, to access environment variables through python, you use `os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')`. Change `DATABASE_URL` to whatever environment variable you're trying to get. Also, make sure you have `import os` before you use `os.environ.get`.

Comment: reload .bash_profile after changing it (i.e. run   . .bash_profile). Also if you are using apache do not use the restart script, but stop and then start it again.

Answer (score 4):

I developed a package that you can install with pip:

```
pip install djangosecure
```

And in your settings.py you could use something like:

```
import djangosecure

...

DATABASES = {
    'default': djangosecure.get_database('production'),
}

...
```

The first time you run a manage command you will be prompted for the database information.

It can be used to secure more settings, see the readme at:
https://github.com/rafahsolis/djangosecure

**Update:**
Updated: djangosecure>=0.0.4 no longer has get_database() function, it now works based on classes so the new ussage would be:

```
from djangosecure import DjangoDatabaseSettings
databases = DjangoDatabaseSettings(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'databases.cnf'), 
crypto_key_file='path/to/your/cryptokey)

DATABASES = {
    'default': 'default': databases.settings('production'),
}
```

Comment: Am I right to understand it use encryption to protect your setting on disk, but key is also present somewhere on disk, so it is possible to crack it having root access? Basically, it solves transfer/source control problem, right?

Comment: That's right, using it you can avoid pushing your passwords by accident to the repository...

Comment: this looks interesting.. Great work @Rafa. im so curious to know how is this better than `os.env.get('DB_PASSWORD', None)`

Comment: The password is saved encrypted using AES256, so it is not saved in plain text at some .profile, so it adds some security. I also like the fact that the database settings are prompt when you run a manage command, lets me change realy fast from one database to another just by changing ...('production') to ...('develop') i would be using diferent database configs